# Clean Solution of Car Fueling problem with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, algorithm

**Car Fueling Problem is** :

You are going to travel to another city that is located  miles away from your home city. Your car can travel at most  miles on a full tank and you start with a full tank. Along your way, there are gas stations at distances stop1 stop2 . . . ,stopN from your home city. What is the minimum number of refills needed?

> **Sample 1**
>
> ***Input***:
>
> 950
>
> 400
>
> 4
>
> 200 375 550 750
>
> ***Output***:
>
> 2
>
> The distance between the cities is **950**, the car can travel at most **400**
> miles on a full tank. It suffices to make two refills: at points **375**
> and **750**. This is the minimum number of refills as with a single refill
> one would only be able to travel at most **800** miles.

> **Sample 2**
>
> ***Input***:
>
> 10
>
> 3
>
> 4
>
> 1 2 5 9
>
> ***Output***:
>
> -1
>
> One cannot reach the gas station at point **9** as the previous gas station is too far away.

I have solved that problem with the below codes but I didn't satisfied with my solution. I think my solution can be more clear than now. Especially, input part which taking inputs from the terminal and sending those inputs to **findMinFuelStops**  function.
May I know how can I use fewer codes to reach the same results and how can I use that approach for my other algorithms?

```
const readline = require("readline");
const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout,
  terminal: false,
});

process.stdin.setEncoding("utf8");
let inputLines = [];
let fuelArr = [];

rl.on("line", readLine);

function readLine(line) {
  let distanceDestination = 0;
  let carCap = 0;
  let availableStops = 0;
  if (inputLines[2] == undefined) {
    inputLines.push(line.toString().split(" ").map(Number));
  } else {
    availableStops = inputLines[2][0];
    fuelArr.push(line.toString().split(" ").map(Number));
    if (fuelArr[0].length > 1) {
      fuelArr = fuelArr[0];
      distanceDestination = inputLines[0][0];
      carCap = inputLines[1][0];

      console.log(
        findMinFuelStops(distanceDestination, carCap, availableStops, fuelArr)
      );

      process.exit();
    } else {
      if (fuelArr.length == availableStops) {
        fuelArr = fuelArr.join(" ").toString().split(" ").map(Number);
        distanceDestination = inputLines[0][0];
        carCap = inputLines[1][0];
        console.log(
          findMinFuelStops(distanceDestination, carCap, availableStops, fuelArr)
        );
        process.exit();
      }
    }
  }
}

function findMinFuelStops(
  distanceDestination,
  carCap,
  availableStops,
  fuelArr
) {
  let countStops = 0;
  let tookDistance = 0;
  const tempCarCap = carCap;

  if (carCap < distanceDestination) {
    for (let i = 0; i < availableStops; i++) {
      if (carCap >= fuelArr[i] - tookDistance) {
        carCap -= fuelArr[i] - tookDistance;
        tookDistance = fuelArr[i];
      } else {
        carCap = tempCarCap;
        if (carCap < fuelArr[i] - tookDistance) {
          countStops = -1;
          return countStops;
        }
        carCap -= fuelArr[i] - tookDistance;
        tookDistance = fuelArr[i];
        countStops++;
      }
    }

    if (carCap >= distanceDestination - tookDistance) {
      carCap = distanceDestination - tookDistance;
      tookDistance = distanceDestination;
    } else {
      carCap = tempCarCap;
      if (carCap < distanceDestination - tookDistance) {
        countStops = -1;
        return countStops;
      }
      tookDistance = distanceDestination;
      countStops++;
      carCap -= distanceDestination - tookDistance;
    }
  }

  return countStops;
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example input line and the desired output?

Comment: I was re-edited the question with an example.

Comment: If there are two gas stations to choose from within the range we currently have available to drive, is there ever a reason to refill at the one that's reached earlier?

Comment: you don't need to refill your car if your gas is enough to reach another gas station.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like it should be relatively straightforward. Iterate over the possible stops. If the next stop is past the tank capacity and the current stop is not past the other city, add the current stop and reset the tank.

If there's a possibility that no path exists, take that into consideration too.

```js
const fn = (targetDistance, tankDistance, stops) => {
  let stopsNeeded = 0;
  let lastStop = 0; // the mileage location of the last stop
  for (let i = 0; i < stops.length; i++) {
    if (lastStop + tankDistance >= targetDistance) {
      return stopsNeeded;
    }
    const stop = stops[i];
    // fail if this stop is out of reach
    if (stop - lastStop > tankDistance) {
      return -1;
    }
    // next stop may be the city
    const nextStop = Math.min(stops[i + 1] ?? targetDistance, targetDistance);
    // If the next stop is out of reach, and this stop is needed, stop here
    if (nextStop - lastStop > tankDistance && stops[i] < targetDistance) {
      stopsNeeded++;
      lastStop = stop;
    }
  }
  return targetDistance - lastStop <= tankDistance ? stopsNeeded : -1;
}
console.log(fn(950, 400, [200, 375, 550, 750]));
console.log(fn(10, 3, [1, 2, 5, 9]));
```

Comment: How can I become to write that kind of algorithm quickly without thinking more? :) I am able to fix the problems by a majority but I don't like my approach. Because mostly I am using more codes than enough for the solution. Do you have any advice or book? Thanks

Comment: Just saying the problem out loud can help - imagine how you'd solve it if it was a problem you were approaching in the real world ("where do I need to stop to have enough gas?"), and then usually, turning that thought process into code shouldn't take much effort - and often won't involve a whole ton of code either.

Answer (score 0):

One of good approach code is on below

```js
function minRefuelStops(target, startFuel, stations) {
  let stopsNeeds = 0;
  let maxR = startFuel; //The point of car maximum can reach.
  let stationI = 0;
  while (maxR < target && stationI < stations.length) {
    while (maxR >= stations[stationI] && stationI < stations.length) {
      stationI++;
    }
    maxR = stations[stationI - 1] + startFuel;
    stopsNeeds++;
    const nextStop= stations[stationI] ==undefined ? target - stations[stationI - 1] : stations[stationI] ;
    if (maxR < nextStop) {
      return -1;
    }
  }
  return target <= maxR ? stopsNeeds : -1;
}
console.log(minRefuelStops(950, 400, [200, 375, 550, 750]));
console.log(minRefuelStops(10, 3, [1, 2, 5, 9]));
```